# how to sharepoint display list name into several languages

Tags: 2010, language, resource-files

I have created a site, installed my language packs, created the term store servcie and created some terms in multi-language (persian and english). I then created a site in which, I created a new list. I gave it a name and then on that list, created a new site column.

I defined 3 resource in 14/resources.

Edit the column by changing the column name to a resource string.($Resources:core,camlid2;)
it is work for me.

but when i changing the list name to a resorce string, it is'nt work !!!

Comment: It is not quit clear what you have been doing. Can you try to write it with more details? Have you created a site collection in a foreign (persian) language having selected in "Select a language" drop-down list the persian?

Comment: if i create new list and set name to ($Resources:core,Customer;), it is work and show (customer /مشتری ). but when i change name of list to it , it isn't work :(